# Hibernate Criteria: NOW() < date + 1 day

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a table in a MySQL DB with a `date(DATETIME)` column on it. How do I express it in java Hibernate criteria if let's say I would like to query for records where `NOW() < ('date' + 1 day)` ?

Comment: Is `NOW()` meant to be based on the database time, or the application server time?

Comment: I would like it to be based on Apps server time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could turn it the other way around and compare `'date' >= (NOW - 1 day)`.

Assuming you've got a mapped `MyTable` class with the `date` property:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyTable.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("date", c.getTime());
List results = criteria.list();
```