# Problems in JOIN using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, join

I'm beginner in Hibernate in JAVA and do not know how to solve this problem

I have two tables: Usuario and Certificado, and i want to create a relationship and theirs.

Class Certificado:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Certificado",
       uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint( columnNames = { "identifierUnique", "handleUser" } ) } )
public class Certificado {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    private int handle;
    @Column(length = 255)
    @Column
    private int handleUser;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="handle_user", referencedColumnName="handle")
    private Usuario usuario;
}
```

Class Usuario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Usuario")
public class Usuario {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    private int handle;
    @Column(length = 255, unique = true)
    private String email;   
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String password;    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="usuario", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Certificado> certificados;

        ...
}
```

When I Execute a SQL function:

```
public static List<Object[]> loadCertificado30DaysBeforeExperation() throws Exception{      
        Session.begin();
        try {
            try {
                String select = "SELECT c FROM Certificado c "
                    + "LEFT JOIN c.handleUser AS user";
                return Session.list(select);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }
        } finally {
            Session.commit();
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3645)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3431)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3309)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1778)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.persistence.Session.list(Session.java:96)
    at br.com.utils.ServletUtils.loadCertificado30DaysBeforeExperation(ServletUtils.java:134)
    at br.com.monitoramento.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:25)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate's HQL does not support intervals ([and generally has extremely poor date maths support](https://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate+date+add)).

You'll need to use native SQL, or express the query without `interval` by doing the date calculations locally on the Java side.

Or you can register a user-defined SQL function and create a PostgreSQL function that does the date maths you want.

See:

- [Performing Date/Time Math In HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/639522/398670)
- [how to use date() in hibernate criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9965560/398670)
- [Hibernate Criteria: NOW() < date + 1 day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15529170/398670)
- [Date operations in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13568914/398670)

and many more.

Comment: i changed sql and occurred another error: NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the '' from '30' -> interval 30 days.
Or escape the '30' -> \'30\'.